# Does this integrand satisfy assumptions of Tonelli's theorem?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, bessel-functions

Because I'm not familiar with Lebesgue integral, please tell me.

I'm worried whether this equality holds:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{ye^{(1-2/x)y}I_{0}(y)f(x)}{x^{3}}dxdy=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ye^{(1-2/x)y}I_{0}(y)f(x)}{x^{3}}dydx,
$$
where $I_{0}$ is the $0$-Bessel function of the first kind and $f$ is non-negative continuous function on $[0,1]$

> **My question**: Does this equality hold?

I know I should use Tonelli's theorem but I don't prove well that this integrand satisfies assumptions of Tonelli's theorem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $I_0$ is nonnegative, then yes. Otherwise: no.

Comment: Thanks for comment, PhoemueX. yes, $I_{0}$ is nonnegative. But could you teach me why assumptions of Tonelli's theorem are satisfied?

Answer (score 1):

1. The sets $(0,1) $ and $(0,\infty ) $ (equipped with Lebesgue measurw) are sigma finite measure spaces (why?).
2. Every continuous function $f : (0,1)\times (0,\infty) \to \Bbb{R} $ is measurable with respect to the product sigma algebra (which coincides with the Borel sigma algebra). In particular, this holds for your integrand. Here, I **assume** that $I_0$ is continous  (I don't know the definition :) ).
3. Since $I_0$ is nonnegative, so is your integrand (why?).

These are all assumptions needed.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to check along your way. By the way, I'm worrid the integrand diverges at $x=0$ but does I not need to take care?

Comment: It can very well be that the integral diverges. But in the case, both sides of the equality will be $\infty $, i.e. the equality still holds.

Comment: I see. I understand! Thank you very much : )